# Pictures vanishing from pdf files

Tags: includegraphics

I have roughly 100 separate pdf files I need to include in a file (supporting info for a thesis). I have copied pictures from Windows' snipping tool onto the .pdf files in adobe acrobat. When I open the files, the picture is there. When I put it into my LaTex file, it is neither shown in in preview nor when I download the pdf.

I use Overleaf, pdfLaTex and the graphicx package. If anyone has a clue as to what is happening and how to fix it, that would be great.

Comment: Have you any error displayed in the code? In Overleaf, you can see a red mark at left of the number line and a red rectangle with a number at right of the "Recompile" button when there is an error. If you see an error, can you display what it is? What is the code used for include a typical image file? Does `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` display an image in the output? ("example-image-a.pdf" is an generic PDF image stored in all LaTeX distributions; see the documentation of the `mwe` package about it, but you don't need to load this package to access to this image example).

Comment: If the mentioning of acrobat means that you added the pictures ad annotations: such annotations get  lost (like links) when you include the pdf. It would have been better to simply save the pictures as png in the snipping tool. You could try to "print" you picture pdf to another pdf to flatten the annotations.

Comment: Shit, I never considered that, but you were right. Adobe seems to treat the pic as comment. I guess there is nothing I can do except exporting them all to jpg, eps or whatever and adapting all the code. Thanks